# Check if method argument is null using illegalargumentexception

Tags: java, templates, exception

I am trying to print the exception message when b is null. However, when I run the program and enter nothing and press enter, it still waits. If I type null or any other string(not number, number works fine), it gives the exception as given below

```
public a<X> insert(X b) {

          if ((b.equals(null))|| (b==null)||(b.equals("null"))||(b.equals("NULL"))){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Argument Exception"); 
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Execption on entering string:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Q.main(a.java:145)
```

Comment: in `(b.equals(null))|| (b==null)` - `b.equals(null)` is meaningless.

Comment: the main problem is not about the condition..it can be changed..the problem is that when I type, for example, string when X is int, I should get illegal argument exception but instead I get the error message as given above

Comment: Can you share a fuller snippet that also includes your use of `Scanner`?

Comment: @Sam If you input something that isn't an integer, `nextInt()` will throw a `InputMismatchException` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()))

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not use any Java method without reading its documentation at least once.

The [documentation for the Scanner.nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) method says:

> Scans the next token of the input as an int.  An invocation of this method of the form `nextInt()` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `nextInt(radix)`, where `radix` is the default radix of this scanner.

So, if we take that documentation's advice and look at the [documentation for Scanner.nextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt-int-), we see:

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below.

When you create a Scanner, the delimiter is whitespace (as stated in the [documentation for the Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)).  When the Scanner is asked to read a value, it will continue to ignore whitespace until it encounters something that isn't whitespace.  Newlines are whitespace, which is why the Scanner is ignoring your pressing of Enter.  It's still waiting for a token.

As the documentation says, alphabetic characters cannot be translated into a valid int value (in the default radix, which is 10), so when you input something like "null" it is throwing an InputMismatchException just like it promised it would.

Your `insert` method has nothing to do with this.

If you want your code to handle non-numeric input, either catch the InputMismatchException, or use `next()` instead of `nextInt()` and parse the String yourself with a NumberFormat.